# Python - Stay in loop Until condition is met

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop

I am wanting to write a loop that stays in the loop until a condition is met.

Here's the code so far, and I'm not sure if all is correct, I have little experience in while loops:

```
x = 2885
y = 1440
difference = 0
while True:
     if x > y:
          difference = x - y
          break
```

So what I want is to keep subtracting my constant `y` from `x` until

```
y > x
```

and to have the final

```
difference = 5
```

Any help is much appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: `x` and `y` never change, so your loop is either endless or ends during the first iteration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wouldn't a better way be to just use modulus.

```
>>> x = 2885
>>> y = 1440
>>> x%y
5
>>>
```

Or still using loops

```
>>> x = 2885
>>> y = 1440
>>> while x >= y :
...     x = x - y
... 
>>> x
5
>>>
```

Comment: How else would you use modulus?

Comment: @ritesht93 Exactly what I was looking for I just didn't know that's what modulus did. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `True` as the condition for execution, just put `x > y`:

```
x = 2885
y = 1440
while x >= y:
   x -= y

>>x
```

Output:

```
5
```

Comment: you should use the condition as `x >= y` or else `1440` would still remain if `x` is exactly divisible (example `x=2880`)

Answer (score 1):

Modulus is your best solution, but this is also possible in a fairly simple for loop if you insist on a looping solution.

```
>>> x = 2885
>>> y = 1440
>>> for i in range(x, -1, -y): # -1 as substitution for inclusive 0
...     pass
...
>>> i
5
```